Mismatched tensors with a Transformer
I recently made a post about an AI I'm making but I've run into some issues.
Here's my code:
import time
full_log = ""
full_log += f"Begin log for train.py\nCurrent time:\n{time.strftime('%d %B, %Y  %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime())} UTC\n{time.strftime('%d %B, %Y  %H:%M:%S', time.localtime())} Local Time (CT)\n\n"


def log(*msgs):
    global full_log
    for msg in msgs:
        print(msg)
        full_log += msg + "\n"

def save_log(PATH="model.log"):
    with open(PATH, "w") as f:
        f.write(full_log)

log("Loading libraries...")
start = time.time_ns()

import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torch.utils.data.dataset import random_split
from torchtext.data.utils import get_tokenizer
from torchtext.vocab import build_vocab_from_iterator
from datasets import load_dataset
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from torch.utils.data.distributed import DistributedSampler
from torch.nn.parallel import DistributedDataParallel as DDP
from torch.distributed import init_process_group, destroy_process_group
import os


log(f"Libraries loaded in {round((time.time_ns() - start) / 1000000, 3)} ms.")

log("Setting config...")
start = time.time_ns()

# device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
torch.set_default_dtype(torch.float64)
epochs = 20
lr = 5.0 # OLD LR = 10.0
lr1_target = 10
batch_size = 32
step_size = 1
gamma = ((lr**(lr1_target-1))**(1/lr1_target))/lr # OLD GAMMA = 0.9
# size of embedding in embedding bag
emsize = 2 ** 12 # 4096
def main(device, world_size):
    def ddp_setup(rank: int, world_size: int):
        """
        Args:
            rank: Unique identifier of each process
           world_size: Total number of processes
        """
        os.environ["MASTER_ADDR"] = "localhost"
        os.environ["MASTER_PORT"] = "25565"
        torch.cuda.set_device(rank)
        init_process_group(backend="nccl", rank=rank, world_size=world_size)

    ddp_setup(device, world_size)
    log(f"Config set. Training on {world_size} GPUs.")

    save_log()

    log("Loading and preprocessing data...")
    start = time.time_ns()

    ds_test = load_dataset("google/civil_comments", split="test")
    ds_train = load_dataset("google/civil_comments", split="train")
    ds_val = load_dataset("google/civil_comments", split="validation")

    log(f"Data loaded and preprocessed in {round((time.time_ns() - start) / 1000000, 3)} ms.")

    log("Building vocabulary...")
    start = time.time_ns()


    tokenizer = get_tokenizer("basic_english")

    try:
        with open("vocab.pth", "rb") as f:
            log("Vocabulary found. Loading...")
            start = time.time_ns()
            vocab = torch.load(f)
            log(f"Vocabulary loaded in {round((time.time_ns() - start) / 1000000, 3)} ms.")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        log("Vocabulary not found. Building...")
        start = time.time_ns()
        def yield_tokens(data):
            for entry in data:
                yield tokenizer(entry["text"])

        vocab = build_vocab_from_iterator(yield_tokens(ds_train), specials=["<unk>"])
        vocab.set_default_index(vocab["<unk>"])
        log(f"Vocabulary built in {round((time.time_ns() - start) / 1000000, 3)} ms.")
        log("Saving vocabulary...")
        start = time.time_ns()
        torch.save(vocab, 'vocab.pth')
        log(f"Vocabulary saved in {round((time.time_ns() - start) / 1000000, 3)} ms.")

    text_pipeline = lambda x: vocab(tokenizer(x))
    label_pipeline = lambda x: int(x)

    log("Generating data batcher and iterator...")
    start = time.time_ns()


    def collate_batch(batch, device):
        labelToxicity_list, labelSevereToxicity_list, labelObscene_list, labelThreat_list, labelInsult_list, labelIdentityAttack_list, labelSexualExplicit_list, text_list, offsets = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [
            0]
        for item in batch:
            labelToxicity = label_pipeline(item["toxicity"])
            labelSevereToxicity = label_pipeline(item["severe_toxicity"])
            labelObscene = label_pipeline(item["obscene"])
            labelThreat = label_pipeline(item["threat"])
            labelInsult = label_pipeline(item["insult"])
            labelIdentityAttack = label_pipeline(item["identity_attack"])
            labelSexualExplicit = label_pipeline(item["sexual_explicit"])
            processed_text = torch.tensor(text_pipeline(item["text"]), dtype=torch.int64)

            labelToxicity_list.append(labelToxicity)
            labelSevereToxicity_list.append(labelSevereToxicity)
            labelObscene_list.append(labelObscene)
            labelThreat_list.append(labelThreat)
            labelInsult_list.append(labelInsult)
            labelIdentityAttack_list.append(labelIdentityAttack)
            labelSexualExplicit_list.append(labelSexualExplicit)

            text_list.append(processed_text)
            offsets.append(processed_text.size(0))

        labelToxicity_list = torch.tensor(labelToxicity_list, dtype=torch.float)
        labelSevereToxicity_list = torch.tensor(labelSevereToxicity_list, dtype=torch.float)
        labelObscene_list = torch.tensor(labelObscene_list, dtype=torch.float)
        labelThreat_list = torch.tensor(labelThreat_list, dtype=torch.float)
        labelInsult_list = torch.tensor(labelInsult_list, dtype=torch.float)
        labelIdentityAttack_list = torch.tensor(labelIdentityAttack_list, dtype=torch.float)
        labelSexualExplicit_list = torch.tensor(labelSexualExplicit_list, dtype=torch.float)
        offsets = torch.tensor(offsets[:-1]).cumsum(dim=0)
        text_list = torch.cat(text_list)

        return (
            labelToxicity_list.to(device),
            labelSevereToxicity_list.to(device),
            labelObscene_list.to(device),
            labelThreat_list.to(device),
            labelInsult_list.to(device),
            labelIdentityAttack_list.to(device),
            labelSexualExplicit_list.to(device),
            text_list.to(device),
            offsets.to(device)
        )


    train_dataloader = DataLoader(ds_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False,
                                  collate_fn=lambda batch: collate_batch(batch, device),
                                  sampler=DistributedSampler(ds_train))
    val_dataloader = DataLoader(ds_val, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False,
                                collate_fn=lambda batch: collate_batch(batch, device),
                                sampler=DistributedSampler(ds_val))
    test_dataloader = DataLoader(ds_test, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False,
                                 collate_fn=lambda batch: collate_batch(batch, device),
                                 sampler=DistributedSampler(ds_test))

    log(f"Data batcher and iterator generated in {round((time.time_ns() - start) / 1000000, 3)} ms.")

    log("Creating model...")
    start = time.time_ns()


    class TextClassificationModel(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, vocab_size, dim, num_class, nhead=8, num_encoder_layers=6, num_decoder_layers=6,
                     dim_feedforward=2048, dropout=0.1, activation='relu', mlp_hidden_size=4096):
            super(TextClassificationModel, self).__init__()
            self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, dim)
            self.transformer = nn.Transformer(d_model=dim, nhead=nhead, num_encoder_layers=num_encoder_layers,
                                              num_decoder_layers=num_decoder_layers, dim_feedforward=dim_feedforward,
                                              dropout=dropout, activation=activation, batch_first=True)
            self.mlp = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(dim, mlp_hidden_size),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(mlp_hidden_size, mlp_hidden_size),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(mlp_hidden_size, num_class)
            )
            self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

        def forward(self, text):
            embedded_text = self.embedding(text)
            x = self.transformer(embedded_text, embedded_text)
            print(x.shape)
            x = x.mean(dim=batch_size)
            x = self.mlp(x)
            print(x.shape)
            return self.sigmoid(x)

    model = TextClassificationModel(len(vocab), emsize, 7).to(device)
    model = DDP(model, device_ids=[device])

    criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size, gamma=gamma)

    log(f"Model created in {round((time.time_ns() - start) / 1000000, 3)} ms.")

    ''' UNCOMMENT TO USE CUSTOM TRAINING PARAMETERS
    custom_params = input("Do you want to use custom training parameters? (y/n): ")
    if custom_params == "y":
        epochs = int(input("Enter number of epochs: "))
        lr = float(input("Enter learning rate: "))
        step_size = int(input("Enter step size: "))
        gamma = float(input("Enter gamma: "))
    '''
    def train(dataloader, device, optimizer, criterion, epoch):

        model.train()
        total_acc, total_count = 0, 0
        log_interval = round(len(dataloader) / 3)
        start_time = time.time()

        for idx, (labelToxicity, labelSevereToxicity, labelObscene, labelThreat, labelInsult, labelIdentityAttack, labelSexualExplicit, text, offsets) in enumerate(dataloader):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            predicted_labels = model(text)
            labels = torch.stack([labelToxicity, labelSevereToxicity, labelObscene, labelThreat, labelInsult, labelIdentityAttack, labelSexualExplicit], dim=1).to(device)
            loss = criterion(predicted_labels, labels)
            loss.backward()
            # torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 0.1)
            optimizer.step()
            total_acc += (predicted_labels.argmax(1) == labels.argmax(1)).sum().item()
            total_count += labels.size(0)
            if idx % log_interval == 0 and idx > 0:
                elapsed = time.time() - start_time
                log(f"| Epoch: {epoch} | {idx}/{len(dataloader)} batches complete | Training time: {round(elapsed, 3)}s | Training accuracy: {round((total_acc / total_count) * 100, 3)}% | Current loss: {round(loss.item(), 3)} |")
                total_acc, total_count = 0, 0
                start_time = time.time()


    def evaluate(dataloader, device):
        model.eval()
        total_acc, total_count = 0, 0

        with torch.no_grad():
            for idx, (labelToxicity, labelSevereToxicity, labelObscene, labelThreat, labelInsult, labelIdentityAttack, labelSexualExplicit, text, offsets) in enumerate(dataloader):
                predicted_labels = model(text)
                labels = torch.stack([labelToxicity, labelSevereToxicity, labelObscene, labelThreat, labelInsult, labelIdentityAttack, labelSexualExplicit], dim=1).to(device)
                loss = criterion(predicted_labels, labels)
                total_acc += (predicted_labels.argmax(1) == labels.argmax(1)).sum().item()
                total_count += labels.size(0)

        return total_acc / total_count



    log("Training model...")
    log(f"Training params:", f"{epochs} epochs | LR = {lr} | Batch size = {batch_size} | Step size = {step_size} | Gamma = {gamma}")
    log(f"Model params:", f"Vocabulary size = {len(vocab)} | Embedding size = {emsize} | Training device = {device}")
    log(f"Device info: {torch.cuda.get_device_name()} | CUDA version: {torch.version.cuda}")
    log("-" * 100)

    total_accu = None

    for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        epoch_start_time = time.time()
        train(train_dataloader, device, optimizer, criterion, epoch)
        accu_val = evaluate(val_dataloader, device)
        if total_accu is not None and total_accu > accu_val:
            scheduler.step()
        else:
            total_accu = accu_val
        log("-" * 100)
        log(f"| End of epoch {epoch} | Elapsed time: {round(time.time() - epoch_start_time,3)}s | Validation accuracy: {round(accu_val * 100, 3)}% | Device temperature: {torch.cuda.temperature()}°C |")
        log("-" * 100)

    log(f"Model trained.")

    log("Testing model with test dataset...")
    start = time.time_ns()

    accu_test = evaluate(test_dataloader)
    log(f"Test accuracy: {round(accu_test * 100, 3)}%")

    log(f"Testing completed in {round((time.time_ns() - start) / 1000000, 3)} ms.")

    try:
        with open("accuracy.txt", "r") as f:
            old_accu = float(f.read())
            if old_accu < accu_test:
                with open("accuracy.txt", "w") as f:
                    f.write(str(accu_test))
                    log(f"New model accuracy ({round(accu_test,5)*100}%) is better than old model accuracy ({round(old_accu,5)*100}%).")
                    log("Saving model...")
                    start = time.time_ns()

                    torch.save(model.module.state_dict(), "model.pth")

                    log(f"Model saved in {round((time.time_ns() - start) / 1000000, 3)} ms.")

            else:
                log(f"New model accuracy ({round(accu_test,5)*100}%) is not better than old model accuracy ({round(old_accu,5)*100}%).")
                log("Model not saved.")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        with open("accuracy.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(str(accu_test))
            log("No old model found. Saving model...")
            start = time.time_ns()

            torch.save(model.module.state_dict(), "model.pth")

            log(f"Model saved in {round((time.time_ns() - start) / 1000000, 3)} ms.")

    save_log(f"model_{time.strftime('%d_%B_%Y_%H_%M_%S', time.gmtime())}.log")
    destroy_process_group()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    world_size = torch.cuda.device_count()
    mp.spawn(main, args=(world_size, ), nprocs=world_size)

It's... a lot.
But I've got this one issue:
torch.Size([1478, 4096])
^^^ transformer output dim


ERROR vvv

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/civilcomments/train.py", line 316, in <module>
    mp.spawn(main, args=(world_size, ), nprocs=world_size)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 246, in spawn
    return start_processes(fn, args, nprocs, join, daemon, start_method="spawn")
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 202, in start_processes
    while not context.join():
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 163, in join
    raise ProcessRaisedException(msg, error_index, failed_process.pid)
torch.multiprocessing.spawn.ProcessRaisedException:

-- Process 4 terminated with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 74, in _wrap
    fn(i, *args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/civilcomments/train.py", line 264, in main
    train(train_dataloader, device, optimizer, criterion, epoch)
  File "/home/ubuntu/civilcomments/train.py", line 223, in train
    predicted_labels = model(text)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1519, in forward
    else self._run_ddp_forward(*inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1355, in _run_ddp_forward
    return self.module(*inputs, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[index]
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/civilcomments/train.py", line 192, in forward
    x = x.mean(dim=batch_size)
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-2, 1], but got 32)

The issue seems to arise when passing the transformer's output to the MLP for regression. I've tried reshaping it, but I just don't know how to make the tensor shapes match!
I'm not sure what to do. I haven't gone to any classes or taken any courses for this, so I don't really know what I'm doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
